# Run Eclipse project on a remote machine

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-plugin, remote-debugging

I have been working on a Java project from my local machine using Eclipse. I am trying to run this on a remote machine. The remote machine is a cluster running on Linux. Right now I have mounted the remote drive and edit the remote file copy through Eclipse. However, I was looking something more robust. Is there any way to do this seamlessly through Eclipse, i.e. each time I run the project, it runs on the remote machine?

Comment: have you tried doing a remote X11 windows session with ssh -X ?

Comment: Yea. It's too slow for day to day use :(

Comment: If your intention is to debug your app remotely through Eclipse IDE remote debugging feature, you can do it as follows http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/opensource/library/os-eclipse-javadebug/index.html

Comment: I have looked at this earlier. Correct me if I am wrong, but it looks like I need to export a jar file and transfer it each time to the remote machine, which is not what I am looking for.

Answer (score 15):

- Set your project output folder to the remote folder you mounted (under Project Properties->Java Build Path).
- Then execute external tool: ssh user@rometesite -c "java -Xdebug -Xrunjdwp:server=y,transport=dt_socket,address=4000,suspend=n Main"
- Launch in eclipse a Remote Java Application (port 4000)

see http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/opensource/library/os-eclipse-javadebug/index.html for more detailed information about remote debug.

Comment: Just to note: on a Mac the command on the second bullet will throw a "Unknown cipher type" error. It works fine without the "-c" flag.

Answer (score 1):

Target management/Remote System Explorer provides plugins to keep a remote directory in sync with your project.  See http://www.eclipse.org/tm/

To run your program remotely, you would probably have to set up an External Tool  launch config (from the Run>External Tools menu) and use a program like ssh to launch your java app remotely on the linux cluster.

Comment: I just checked out RSE. It allows me to edit remote file, but I don't see any option to sync the local project to my remote machine. Am I missing something ?

Comment: It looks like RSEs primary value is remote editing.  See http://wiki.eclipse.org/TM_and_RSE_FAQ#How_can_I_use_a_remote_workspace_over_SSH.3F and https://bugs.eclipse.org/195997

Answer (score 0):

Here is a great tutorial to do it :
http://help.eclipse.org/juno/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.jdt.doc.user%2Freference%2Fpreferences%2Fjava%2Fdebug%2Fref-execution_environments.htm
 and this one is usefull too : http://java.dzone.com/articles/how-debug-remote-java-applicat

Answer (score -1):

This sounds like a great situation for a [continuous integration](http://martinfowler.com/articles/continuousIntegration.html) solution.  Have you considered setting up [CruiseControl](http://cruisecontrol.sourceforge.net/)?  I realize that might seem like overkill if you're just a single developer working on something.  And if you don't want to move a JAR file over to the remote machine you probably won't be up for this either.

But continuous integration is worth the trouble once it's set up.  Beyond the automated deployment (which is what you're asking for here) you'll get a debug/test environment that everyone in your group can use.  Plus it forces you to solve the packaging/deployment problems up front which, while not fun, gets you one big step closer towards a truly iterative development process.

Comment: The question is about ad-hoc, in-dev running of an app in a remote cluster and not about CI/CD.